# Why does Mockito expects my verification method to be called with `Nothing`?

Tags: java, kotlin, mocking, mockito, ros

In my project I tried to setup a test in which should be verified that a method is called with a specific parameter. For this I am using Mockito and Kotlin.

In the test I am using a mock class. (`publisher`) This class is part of rosjava and contains a method `publish`;

```
public interface Publisher<T> extends TopicParticipant { //(java)
    void setLatchMode(boolean var1);

    boolean getLatchMode();

    T newMessage();

    void publish(T var1);

    boolean hasSubscribers();

    int getNumberOfSubscribers();

    void shutdown(long var1, TimeUnit var3);

    void shutdown();

    void addListener(PublisherListener<T> var1);
}
```

When I try to set my expectation like:

```
val publisherMock = mock(Publisher::class.java)

verify(publisherMock, atLeastOnce()).publish(message) // message is underlined with a red color
```

This does not compile and says that the parameter for `publish` should be of class `Nothing!`. Why is this?

Comment: do you have a class called Nothing which you use in this flow?

Comment: No, I think it is referring to the Nothing class of Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `Publisher` class is generic. Creating mock with `mock(Publisher::class.java)` code creates `Publisher<*>` object (it means that type parameter is `Nothing`).

To solve it you can't just place type parameter in mock creating code - `Publisher<String>::class.java` is not a valid code for Java or Kotlin.

All you can do is unchecked cast:

```
val publisherMock = mock(Publisher::class.java) as Publisher<String>
```

If you need to disable warning from `Android Studio` just place `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` line before that.